# Get index from bytebuffer

Tags: java, offset, bytebuffer

I have to read a byteBuffer in Java.
I a m using `byteBuffer.get()` but when I read a specific value, I have to get the offset in the byteBuffer. How can I do that ?

For example

```
byte name = byteBuffer.get();
byte location = byteBuffer.get();

for (int i=1; i<16; i++){
    //Here I want to get the offset in the byteBuffer like bytebuffer.getOffsset() or something like that
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    byteBuffer.get(myObject);
}
```

I want to get all offset for each "MyObject"
Is there something to do to get these offsets ?

Comment: How do you store objects in a `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: could you be more specific ? do want the current position in the buffer or what ? and as mentioned in the above comment how do you store an object in a bytebuffer ?

Comment: There is no such method as `ByteBuffer.get(MyObject)` or even `ByteBuffer.get(Object)`. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int offset = byteBuffer.position();
```

This is a method of the Buffer class, hence you probably overlooked it.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for ! Thank you